# How do I create a custom namespace or class in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create my own namespace, something like **$** for **JQuery**

```
 (function(app) {
     app.fn.log = function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        };
 }(app));

 app.log("data");
```

But this code returns an error -  **Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined**

How do I create my own namespace?

Comment: Well, where's `app` defined? The function takes an `app` argument and you pass an `app` variable, that doesn't exist...

Comment: I do not know how and where should I implant that

Comment: See if this helps http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript

Comment: I think you must read books about javascript, codeacademy ))

Comment: I can define that with {} , and it works well, but I can not use just custum namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.app = {};

(function(app) {
    app.log = function(data) {
         console.log(data);
       };
}(app));

app.log("data");
```

jQuery deals a little bit different with it's `fn`: as you use `$('selector')` syntax to find elements you need to process jQuery returns spetial *wrapper* that contains all the `fn.func`-like definitions you made in addition to the built-in functions.

So if you need to implement some kind of extensibility you should think over such wrapping first. For example:

```
window.app = function(p) {

    // do whatever you need

    var wrapper = {
        // standard common fields
    };

    if (app.fn) {
        // extend wrapper with app.fn
    }

    return wrapper;
};
```

By the way what problem are you trying to solve?

In your case there is of course an exception because `app` in not defined by the time anonymous function gets executed.

Comment: thanks, yes it works well now, but I hope you know my other question, as you can see console.log(data); shows the line in browser that this function called, is there any way to pass show the line that was called by function ? I mean show line that I call app.log('data');

Comment: What means `line`? Line number?

Comment: It is not possible unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

A common approach for implementing namespacing in javascript is to leverage the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) with immediate functions for scoping (like you demonstrated in your question). This also allows you to pass in objects with non-conflicting names and use them with parameterized names that you would prefer such as `$` like so:

```
//Global script declaration
var NAMESPACE = {};

//Check if you need to initialize your namespace
NAMESPACE.FooSpace = NAMESPACE.FooSpace || {};

//Some other script
NAMESPACE.FooSpace = (function($) {
    function Foo1() {
    }

    function Foo2() {
        return $.getSomething(); //some existing function inside of someObjectWithANonConflictingName object
    }    

    return { Foo1: Foo1, Foo2: Foo2 };
})(someObjectWithANonConflictingName);

//somewhere else in code (call as a constructor function)
var foo = new NAMESPACE.FooSpace.Foo1();
//somewhere else in code (call as regular function)
var foo2 = Foo2();
```

- This approach will help prevent naming conflicts because you can simply add to the `NAMESPACE` object in order to have overlapping names of functions and variables.
- It also gives you the added benefit of being able to renamed variables or functions to something that would otherwise conflict with popular libraries.
- In addition, this helps really cut down on global namespace because it all is held within the `NAMESPACE` object.
- It affords you an alternative option to attaching something to the window object (some find this distasteful).

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is ok, but you have to define an `app`. You are passing the app as parameter to your [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), but app is not defined! If you wanted to access jQuery as app, simply call your IIFE with jQuery object like this:

```
(function(app) {
     app.fn.log = function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        };
 }($)); // where $ is your jQuery.
```

and

```
$.log("data");
```

Beware! The log function will be available inside and outside the scope of IIFE!